# Read in a csv file as a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wrote a Python Script which analyses CSV files.
I want to implement a file picker, so when I execute the script it should open Windows Explorer and let me choose my file which it should analyse.
So far it reads 1 file manually:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('file1.csv', usecols=['col1', 'col2'])
```

I want to replace file1.csv with a variable, so everytime I execute the script I can choose a different File.

```
file = open.windowsexplorer (choose file from directory)
df=pd.read_csv (' ' +  file', usecols='col1', 'col2'])
```

Furthermore I would like to do the same with the columns. So I can type in the column names I want to choose. In case in other Files the columns are named differently:

column1 = type in here

column2 = type in here (as a windows alert)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a bare code that should do what you are asking:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, filetypes=[("CSV Files",".csv")])
col1 = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Column 1", parent=root, initialvalue="col1")
col2 = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Column 2", parent=root, initialvalue="col2")

df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=[col1, col2])
```

You will find additional information about simple dialogs [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html).

Comment: @Michelle You are welcome, read [mcve] in order to ask better question next time and not having downvote as you got.